# Default values for arrays members of struct

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, struct, initialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Intitialzing an array in a C++ class and modifiable lvalue problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647038/intitialzing-an-array-in-a-c-class-and-modifiable-lvalue-problem)

As seen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069621/are-members-of-a-c-struct-initialized-to-0-by-default) question, it's possible to give a ctor to a struct to make it members get default values. How would you proceed to give a default value to every element of an array inside a struct.

```
struct foo
{
   int array[ 10 ];
   int simpleInt;
   foo() : simpleInt(0) {}; // only initialize the int...
}
```

Is there some way to make this in one line similar to how you would do to initialize an int?

Comment: @Francis: As written right now, this code doesn't work in C, since it uses a constructor. Constructors are a C++ feature.

Comment: @Francis: No it doesn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thew new C++ standard has a way to do this:

```
struct foo
{
   int array[ 10 ];
   int simpleInt;
   foo() : array{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}, simpleInt(0) {};
};
```

test: https://ideone.com/enBUu

If your compiler does not support this syntax yet, you can always assign to each element of the array:

```
struct foo
{
   int array[ 10 ];
   int simpleInt;
   foo() : simpleInt(0)
   {
        for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
            array[i] = i;
   }
};
```

EDIT: one-liner solutions in pre-2011 C++ require different container types, such as C++ vector (which is preferred anyway) or boost array, which can be [boost.assign](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/assign/doc/index.html)'ed

```
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
struct foo
{
    boost::array<int, 10> array;
    int simpleInt;
    foo() : array(boost::assign::list_of(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(7)(8)(9)(10)),
            simpleInt(0) {};
};
```

Comment: So there is no _one liner_ for this type of operation?

Comment: @Francis - by "one liner" do you mean "in the ctor-initializer"? If it's a "one liner" you're seeking, just hoist the ctor body onto the same line (I'm not being snarky, just trying to understand your comment a little better)

Comment: @Dan - I was referring to ctor-initializer

Comment: What do you mean by "which is preferred anyway"?

Answer (score 4):

Changing the array to a std::vector will allow you to do simple initialization and you'll gain the other benefits of using a vector.

```
#include <vector>
struct foo
{
  std::vector<int> array;
  int simpleInt;
  foo() : array(10, 0), simpleInt(0) {}; // initialize both
};
```

Comment: You will also get the negatives of using a vector.

Comment: @Moberg which are?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to default-initialize the array (setting built-in types to 0), you can do it like this:

```
struct foo
{
   int array[ 10 ];
   int simpleInt;
   foo() : array(), simpleInt(0) { }
};
```

Comment: There is no way to assign a default value other than 0?

Comment: @Francis:  Not prior to C++0x, no.  For alternatives, see the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <algorithm>

struct foo
{
  int array[ 10 ];
  int simpleInt;
  foo() : simpleInt(0) { std::fill(array, array+10, 42); }
};
```

or use `std::generate(begin, end, generator);` where the generator is up to you.