# looking for another time structure with member objects other than tm

Tags: c++, tm, ctime

the member `tm_mon`, in `struct tm` is stored as an integer. I'm looking for another time `stuct` that stores the actual name of the month. I can get the user-friendly format with

```
ctime();
```

but how can I selectively output just the month?

Answer (score 1):

Have an array like,

```
string Months[] = {"January", "February", ... };
```

Then when you want to print use,

```
time_t t = time(0);   // get time now
struct tm * now = localtime( & t );
cout << Months[now-> tm_mon];
```

Comment: Thanks! That's actually simpler lol

but why will it let me make a string array in int main but not in a struct outside of int main??

Comment: This may help solve your issue! 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652165/default-values-for-arrays-members-of-struct

Comment: @BenMarconi you can upvote and mark as the answer if you found it useful! ;)